# Redefine a single method on an instance to call superclass method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have two Rails models: `Person` and `Administrator`. We're disallowing removal of `Administrator`s at the model level:

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Administrator < Person
  def destroy
    raise "Can't remove administrators."
  end
end

me = Administrator.new
me.destroy              # raises an exception
```

I'd like to be able to get around this during testing, but only for specific instances created during setup and teardown. I don't want to change the behavior of the class, so `class_eval` and `remove_method` aren't feasible.

I tried to redefine the actual instance's `#destroy` method:

```rb
def me.destroy
  super
end
```

or redefine it on the singleton class:

```rb
class << me
  def destroy
    super
  end
end
```

but those still raised the exception. I couldn't figure out how to get it to call the superclass method implicitly. I ended up creating my own `destroy!` method (since that's not actually a method in ActiveRecord), which sort of violates my desire not to change the behavior of the class:

```rb
def destroy!
  ActiveRecord::Persistence.instance_method(:destroy).bind(self).call
end
```

Is there any simple way to tell a single instance method to call its superclass method?

---

**Final Answer:** Based on the article Holger Just linked to, I was able to simply call the superclass method explicitly:

```rb
def me.destroy
  self.class.superclass.instance_method(:destroy).bind(self).call
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to refactor the behavior to be more test-friendly. E.g. you could allow an optional parameter to destroy e.g. `i_know_what_im_doing` that has to be set to true to carry out the destroy. Alternatively you could [cancel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#label-Canceling+callbacks) the `destroy` with a `before_destroy` hook like

```
class Administrator < Person
  def before_destroy(record)
    # You can't destroy me
    false
  end
end
```

In your tests, you can then call `Administrator.skip_callback :before_destroy` to ignore it and to have a proper destroy.

Finally, you could overwrite / stub the method in your tests. While you say you don't want to modify the class's behavior, you still have to do that (and implicitly do that with your `destroy!` method today).

Comment: Thanks, Holger. Your suggestions are great, but I'm mostly curious why my calls to `super` were failing to call the superclass method. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: With your construct, you created the overridden destroy method on the singleton class (also called eigenclass) of your `me` instance. If you are in the scope of that method, the super chain is as follows: eigenclass -> class -> modules included into the class -> parent class ... That means the your `super` call on your `destroy` method on `me` calls the `destroy` method on your `Aministrator` class. For more info about the concept of the eigenclass, see [this great article](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ruby metaprograming, so I wont answer if you can a call a method of the super class on an instance without modifying it. But you can create a hook to a superclass method with `alias` :

```
class Administrator < Person

  alias :force_destroy :destroy 

  def destroy
    raise "Can't remove administrators."
  end
end
```

With this, `admin.destroy` will raise an exception, but `admin.force_destroy` will actually call the ActiveRecord destroy.